# How to expose an Objective-C++ class to swift without prototyping it in the .h file

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, swift

I'm trying to use a C++ library in my Swift project and until now, it works fine, except that I have a little problem when I'm trying to include a .h that contains C++ code in a .h of one of my Objective-C++ .h file.

Here is the situation in picture :

[image: .h file]

Here is the .h of my Objective-C++ class. As you can see, the init method take in parameter a `SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayerCallback`, this type is declared in the file `SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer.h` that is a file of the lib written in C++, so I include it.

But the problem is that I cannot include C++ code except in .mm file, otherwise, Xcode won't compile and says:

[image: Error message]

So I tried to move all the `@interface` block and the `#import "SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer.h"` of my `SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayerWrapped.h` file in my .mm file but with that my `SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayerWrapped` is not exposed to my Swift file, logic, the `SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayerWrapped.h` file (that I include in file Bridging-Header) is now empty.

And if I only move the `#import "SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer.h"` in my .mm file, Xcode will not compile and says that `SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayerCallback` is not a type, logic too...

So I'm stuck with that, as I'm not an Objective-C++ expert.

Any idea to solve this ?

Comment: Please, post code and error message instead of giving a picture of it

Comment: Replace class with Class?

Comment: Try `#include "SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer.h"` instead of `#import`.  Also, Superpowered distribution comes with a few samples.  Check if they have one that uses a callback and see how they deal with it.  I'm at work now, will check into this more once I get home.  And, as @Garf365 pointed out, it's better not to use pictures; in fact, i recall there is a site rule against it.

Comment: I don't think replacing `#import` with `#include` will help, sorry, even though I've seen `#include` typically used to import C++ code into Objective-C(++).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that C++ types, such as `SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer`, cannot be exposed to Objective-C or Swift, but only to Objective-C++. Thus your wrapper, since it uses C++ classes, needs to be implemented in Objective-C++.  The wrapper's header(s), i.e. the `.h` file(s), should not reference any C++ code.

I've seen a few uses of callbacks in the examples that come with `Superpowered`, and they typically implement the callbacks in Objective-C++ (.mm) files.  You can search the code yourself, since it would not be very informative for the community to look at the product-specific examples.

What I might do in this case is

- Not include the `SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer.h` header into the
  header that declares the `SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayerWrapped`
  interface.
- Express the interface in `..Wrapped.h` in terms of custom data types
  that will be implemented in `.mm` files, and that's where C++ code
  will be referenced.

For example, you could introduce a `SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayerCallbackWrapped` type that will be passed to the `..Wrapped` `init` method.

The following is a mock-up example of how something like this could be done.  First, here is some C++ code that we want to call from Swift (`mylib.cpp`):

```
#include "mylib.hpp"

MyCpp::MyCpp(MyCppCallback cb, int i) : m_CB(cb), m_Int(i) {}

int MyCpp::f(int i)
{
    return m_CB(i + m_Int);
}
```

and the corresponding header file (`mylib.hpp`):

```
#ifndef mylib_hpp
#define mylib_hpp

/**
 * Callback type used by the C++ code.
 */
typedef int (*MyCppCallback) (int);

/**
 * A simple C++ class.  
 */
class MyCpp
{
public:
    MyCpp(MyCppCallback, int);
    int f(int);
private:
    MyCppCallback m_CB;
    int m_Int;
};

#endif /* mylib_hpp */
```

The header, `mylib.hpp`, cannot be included in a Swift bridging header directly or indirectly, so we need a wrapper.  BTW, the extension could be `.h` instead of `.hpp`, it doesn't really matter.

The wrapper code has to be Objective-C++ because it utilizes a C++ type (`MyCpp`), here it is (`wrapper.mm`):

```
#import "mylib.hpp"
#import "wrapper.h"

@implementation MyWrapper
{
    MyCpp * pMyCpp;
}

-(id)init: (wrapper_cb_t)cb withInt: (int)i
{
    pMyCpp = new MyCpp( cb, i );
    return self;
}

-(int)f: (int)i
{
    return pMyCpp->f(i);
}

@end
```

And here is the corresponding header, `wrapper.h`, that can be included in a Swift bridging header because it is free of any C++ stuff:

```
#ifndef wrapper_h
#define wrapper_h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

/**
 * Here we just repeat the callback typedef from mylib.hpp.  We can do this because
 * it does not depend on C++ types.  If it did, we could come up with some
 * "glue" code in wrapper.mm.
 */
typedef int (*wrapper_cb_t) (int);

/**
 * This is the wrapper interface.  It doesn't depend on any C++ types.
 */
@interface MyWrapper : NSObject

-(id)init: (wrapper_cb_t)cb withInt: (int)i;
-(int)f: (int)i;

@end

#endif /* wrapper_h */
```

The bridging header looks like this:

```
#import "wrapper.h"
```

and here is sample Swift code using the C++ code via the wrapper:

```
/**
 * This is a Swift callback function of type wrapper_cb_t.
 * To figure out how the wrapper's signature is imported into Swift,
 * just type "wrapper_cb_t" somewhere in the code, click on it, and
 * Xcode Quick Help should show you the signature.
 */
func swift_cb(i: Int32) -> Int32
{
    return i + 111
}

/**
 * Now create an instance of MyWrapper...
 */
let w : MyWrapper = MyWrapper(swift_cb, withInt: 3)

/**
 * ... and use it:
 */
print("f() in the wrapper returned \(w.f(4))")
```

This sample is a very simplified piece of code and doesn't claim to be production quality.  E.g., memory management is not covered.

Please note that once you start dealing with callbacks, things get a lot more complicated than just having Swift call Objective-C/C++ code.  Now you have to write code that will be called by C and/or C++.  You will find a lot of interesting info on that if you search for "Swift callback c" in this forum or Google.